# Regarding edit summary input validation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

I am writing this to inform you about a little bug (input validation) in your site.

As I am active on your site, I found that whenever I edit an answer given by any user, I have to pass text in the "Edit Summary" field at the end of the edited answer.

Now, it should be a proper and real edit summary, but I have checked it by writing **12345679801234567890**. That is, any non-text value or number value, and it accepts it which it should not do.

This is a request to fix it.

Comment: Note that at least one high-rep user routinely puts poetic nonsense in his edit summaries.

Comment: You also want AI to analyze your text and make sure it's correct according to what you edited? Really... it's ***your responsibility as the one who edit to give proper summary***. Simple as that.

Comment: @Nathan I'm dying of curiosity; who's that guy?

Comment: @IͶΔ Certainly not a random user...

Comment: @IͶΔ: [This here dude](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/9314/random?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

Comment: @NathanTuggy ... 0.o and they just get away with that?

Answer (score 11):

We're not going to implement language recognition for the edit summary field. :) If nothing else, we support sites in various languages, and... just no. That way lies madness.

If someone makes a bunch of bad edits *along with* bad summaries, they're just going to get suspended and we'll call the problem handled. If the edits are good... the content of the summary doesn't matter that much, although it's polite and/or a good idea to explain what was changed for future readers.

Comment: "going to get suspended" - don't you mean "edit banned"? (unless you mean 2k users who can't be edit banned)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Does it matter? Point is that it'll get dealt with in ways that don't require a technical solution to the "bogus summaries" potential problem.